# New Data save to Mutable Array in Parse not calling save function

Tags: ios, nsmutablearray, parse-platform

I have a module that saves data based on user inputs from text fields and adds it to an array saved in Parse.  Testing with pre-populated data the module works fine.  However, if I go to add data where there previously wasn't any it causes the app to ignore the saving element all together.  What is the best way to add new arrays to Parse where no previous data existed?  Here is the existing code:

```
- (IBAction)saveButton:(id)sender
{
[getData showGlobalProgressHUDWithTitle:@"Saving Test"];
PFQuery *tankQuery = [PFQuery queryWithClassName:@"WaterTests"];
[tankQuery whereKey:@"tankObjectId" equalTo:_passedValue];

[tankQuery findObjectsInBackgroundWithBlock:^(NSArray *objects, NSError *error) {
    if (!error)
    {
        for (PFObject *object in objects)
        {
            calciumArray    =  [object valueForKey:@"calciumArray"];
            nitrateArray    =  [object valueForKey:@"nitrateArray"];
            phosArray       =  [object valueForKey:@"phosphateArray"];
            salinityArray   =  [object valueForKey:@"salinityArray"];
            alkArray        =  [object valueForKey:@"alkArray"];
            phArray         =  [object valueForKey:@"phArray"];
            tempArray       =  [object valueForKey:@"tempArray"];

            [calciumArray   addObject:  addCalcium.text];
            [nitrateArray   addObject:  addNitrate.text];
            [phosArray      addObject:  addPhosphate.text];
            [salinityArray  addObject:  addSalinity.text];
            [alkArray       addObject:  addAlk.text];
            [phArray        addObject:  addPH.text];
            [tempArray      addObject:  addTemp.text];

            [object saveInBackgroundWithBlock:^(BOOL succeeded, NSError *error) {
                if (!error)
                {
                    NSLog(@"Something happened");
                    [getData dismissGlobalHUD];
                    [self hideTestView];
                }
                else
                {
                    NSLog(@"Nothing happened: %@", error);
                }
                [self resignFirstResponder];
                [_chartView reloadData];
            }];
        }
    }
}];
}
```

I know that I'm close, but don't quite understand why it's not firing off the saving code.  I believe its because I'm trying to retrieve objects that are empty first, but I could be wrong about that.  Anyone have any advice for this?

*UPDATE*  Here is the ViewDidLoad Code as it pertains to retrieving the data.

```
- (void)viewDidLoad
{
    self.title = @"Water Quality";

    statQuery = [PFQuery queryWithClassName:@"WaterTests"];
    [statQuery whereKey:@"tankObjectId" equalTo:_passedValue];
    [statQuery findObjectsInBackgroundWithBlock:^(NSArray *objects, NSError *error)
     {
         if (!error)
         {
             for (PFObject *object in objects)
             {
                 [statQuery whereKey:@"tankObjectId" equalTo:_passedValue];
                 calciumArray = [object valueForKey:@"calciumArray"];
                 _footerView.sectionCount = calciumArray.count;
                 NSLog(@"CALCIUM ARRAY: %@", calciumArray);
                 nitrateArray = [object valueForKey:@"nitrateArray"];
                 NSLog(@"NITRATE ARRAY: %@", nitrateArray);
                 phosArray = [object valueForKey:@"phosphateArray"];
                 NSLog(@"PHOSPHATE ARRAY: %@", phosArray);
                 salinityArray = [object valueForKey:@"salinityArray"];
                 NSLog(@"SALINITY ARRAY: %@", salinityArray);
                 alkArray = [object valueForKey:@"alkArray"];
                 NSLog(@"ALKALINITY ARRAY: %@", alkArray);
                 phArray = [object valueForKey:@"phArray"];
                 NSLog(@"PH ARRAY: %@", phArray);
                 tempArray = [object valueForKey:@"tempArray"];
                 NSLog(@"TEMPERATURE ARRAY: %@", tempArray);
             }
         }
         if (calciumArray == nil || [calciumArray count] == 0)
         {
             NSLog(@"You should probably fire off the new test function here.");
             [_chartView setUserInteractionEnabled:NO];
             [self newTest:self];
             NSLog(@"Error: %@", error);
         }
     }];
```

This is the only other time the data is mentioned at all in the view.  I allocate and initialize the arrays elsewhere, but I don't think that's the problem considering existing arrays pull and save just fine.

Comment: Your code seems good. Did you check the parse site that if object's are been added to it and also check with your where condition. Also check for obejcts with nslog if no error.

Comment: Also for saving you could write as PFObject *userObj = [PFObject objectWithClassName:@"CLASS_NAME"];
    userObj[@"name"] = @"TEXT_TO_SAVE";

Comment: Its saving correctly only if theres existing pre populated data. (I entered a few values myself in Parse). Still unsure of why. Do you need to see more?

Comment: Yes , do provide more info and screen shot. Also what error you getting?!

Comment: No error. It just skips the save portion entirely and the ui elements that dismiss are stuck there

Comment: Updated with new code.

Comment: Try this, create a array of objects and add those object's in for-lopp .As for-loop is done then call **saveInBackgroundWithBlock** and remove it from for-loop. Call it outside for-loop and save array in a go. Or you could call [object save] as in background might mess up with for-loop running. So give it a try !

Comment: Could you perhaps illustrate this in code? It's almost 5am where I am and I've been up all night; mind isn't the sharpest.

Comment: Try this, it might work. for (PFObject *object in objects)
            {
                calciumArray    =  [object valueForKey:@"calciumArray"];
                .
                .
                .
                
                
                [arrayMu]
                [calciumArray   addObject:  addCalcium.text];
                .
                .
                .
                
                [objects save]; //Instead of saveinbackground.
            }

Comment: @walle84 that's not really  readable; can you expand that into an answer?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I was able to properly add a new array from a single object if nothing else was available by plainly adding a new object to Parse:

```
- (IBAction)saveButton:(id)sender
{
    [getData showGlobalProgressHUDWithTitle:@"Saving Test"];
    PFQuery *tankQuery = [PFQuery queryWithClassName:@"WaterTests"];
    [tankQuery whereKey:@"tankObjectId" equalTo:_passedValue];
    PFObject *testObject = [[PFObject alloc] initWithClassName:@"WaterTests"];

    [tankQuery findObjectsInBackgroundWithBlock:^(NSArray *objects, NSError *error) {
        if (objects.count == 0)
        {
            [testObject setObject:_passedValue forKey:@"tankObjectId"];
            [testObject addObject:addCalcium.text forKey:@"calciumArray"];
            [testObject addObject:addNitrate.text forKey:@"nitrateArray"];
            [testObject addObject:addPhosphate.text forKey:@"phosphateArray"];
            [testObject addObject:addSalinity.text forKey:@"salinityArray"];
            [testObject addObject:addAlk.text forKey:@"alkArray"];
            [testObject addObject:addPH.text forKey:@"phArray"];
            [testObject addObject:addTemp.text forKey:@"tempArray"];

            [testObject saveInBackgroundWithBlock:^(BOOL succeeded, NSError *error) {
                if (!error)
                {
                    [getData dismissGlobalHUD];
                    [self hideTestView];
                    NSLog(@"Something, somewhere, saved.");
                }
                else
                {
                    NSLog(@"HOORAY ERROR: %@", error);
                }
                [_chartView reloadData];
            }];
        }
```

However, I also had to check to see if there were any objects to begin with.  If there were not any, simply add them in new.  If there were, I had to run the code to query the database and add a `for` loop for every object that was found with the given criteria:

```
        else if (objects.count != 0)
        {
            for (PFObject *object in objects)
            {
                [object addObject:addCalcium.text forKey:@"calciumArray"];
                [object addObject:addNitrate.text forKey:@"nitrateArray"];
                [object addObject:addPhosphate.text forKey:@"phosphateArray"];
                [object addObject:addSalinity.text forKey:@"salinityArray"];
                [object addObject:addAlk.text forKey:@"alkArray"];
                [object addObject:addPH.text forKey:@"phArray"];
                [object addObject:addTemp.text forKey:@"tempArray"];

                [object saveInBackgroundWithBlock:^(BOOL succeeded, NSError *error)
                {
                    if (!error)
                    {
                        [getData dismissGlobalHUD];
                        [self hideTestView];
                        [_chartView reloadData];
                        NSLog(@"Here we go again");
                    }
                }];
            }
        }
    }];
}
```

I'm submitting this as my own answer and offering this to the community wiki to help others figure out similar problems.  Problem: SOLVED!

Answer (score 0):

```
(PFObject *object in objects) 
{ 
  calciumArray = [object valueForKey:@"calciumArray"]; 
  . 
  . 
  . //Other object for array

  [arrayMu] [calciumArray addObject: addCalcium.text]; //Add in NSMutableArray
  .
  .
  . 
  [objects save]; //Instead of saveinbackground.
}
```

Try this out. Also do reply back in time as after a long time I had would have to read all your query again as not in touch with it.

UPADTE...

```
-(IBAction)updateButton:(id)sender
{
 PFQuery *query = [PFQuery queryWithClassName:@"UserDetail"];

 NSString *str =self.nameTextField.text;

 [query whereKey:@"name" containsString:str];

 [query getFirstObjectInBackgroundWithBlock:^(PFObject *object, NSError *error)
 {
     if (!error)
     {
         NSLog(@"Successfully retrieved: %@", [object objectId]); //I retrieve the object succesfully 

         object[@"job"] = self.jobTextField.text;   //Made changes to it.
         object[@"hobby"] = self.hobbyTextField.text;

         [object saveInBackground];  //Again saved it in background
     }
     else
     {
         NSLog(@"Error: %@", [error localizedDescription]);
     } }];
```

}

Then I checked my parse db and my data was modified.

Comment: Thanks. I'll be trying it soon

Comment: For whatever reason, this is producing the same problem as before.  It just completely ignores the block.